# SQL variables and the IF statement

Tags: t-sql, variables, if-statement, ssms, sqlcmd

I am using T-SQL in SQLCMD mode in SSMS to run various subfile from one file, and the principle file (princ.sql) is where I need to declared and set a variable @MyInteger and run a subfile:

```
DECLARE @MyInteger INT
SET @MyInteger = 20

:setvar path "your absolute file path here"

:r $(path)\"query.sql"
:r $(path)\"uses Myingteger too.sql"
```

This works fine; as a minimal example, consider query.sql and 'uses MyInteger too.sql' to have the same one line

```
SELECT @MyInteger
```

and i do get back two instances of 20.

My trouble is that I would like to be able to run query.sql on its own using a locally defined variable @SubMyInteger.
My ideal situation for query.sql is

```
IF @MyInteger is declared 
    SET @SubMyInteger = @MyInteger
ELSE 
    SET @SubMyInteger = 90

SELECT @SubMyInteger
```

Then when I run query.sql, @MyInteger would not have been declared, so @SubMyInteger would be assigned 90, and 90 would be returned. I would also get back two 20s as before if i ran princ.sql

For the IF statement, I have so far tried two things:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('@MyInteger') IS NOT NULL
```

and

```
IF @MyInteger IS NOT NULL
```

I get the error

```
Must declare scalar variable "@MyInteger".
```

If I try declaring @MyInteger and then run princ.sql, I get the error

```
The variable '@MyInteger' has already been declared.
```

even if the declare statement is conditioned with an IF.

Is there a way to achieve what I want here?

Thanks

Comment: The path seems to need to be absolute, so I edited it out, and forgot to put it back in. I'm betting this is what your error probably has to do with. Is it?

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway: it's not possible to (cleanly) tell if a variable is declared, but you *could* see if it has had a 'useful value assigned'.